# parsing data using pandas with fixed sequence of strings

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have data looked like below in file a.dat:

```
01/Jul/2016 00:05:09      8438.2
01/Jul/2016 00:05:19      8422.4 g
```

I wish to parsing them into three columns: **timeline, floating number, string(either None or g)**

I have tried:

```
df=pd.read_csv('a.dat',sep='      | ',engine='python')
```

which ends up with 4 columns: date, time , float and g

```
df=pd.read_csv('a.dat',sep='      | (g)',engine='python')
```

which gives 5 columns with column 1 and 4 as NaN

is there any better way to create the dataframe without any post processing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''01/Jul/2016 00:05:09      8438.2
01/Jul/2016 00:05:19      8422.4 g'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep='\s+', 
                 names=['date','time','float','string'], 
                 parse_dates=[['date','time']])
print (df)
            date_time   float string
0 2016-07-01 00:05:09  8438.2    NaN
1 2016-07-01 00:05:19  8422.4      g
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''01/Jul/2016 00:05:09      8438.2
01/Jul/2016 00:05:19      8422.4 g'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 delim_whitespace=True, 
                 names=['date','time','float','string'], 
                 parse_dates=[['date','time']])
print (df)
            date_time   float string
0 2016-07-01 00:05:09  8438.2    NaN
1 2016-07-01 00:05:19  8422.4      g
```

---

Solution with [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''01/Jul/2016 00:05:09      8438.2  
01/Jul/2016 00:05:19      8422.4 g'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 names=['date','time','float','string'], 
                 parse_dates=[['date','time']])
print (df)
            date_time   float string
0 2016-07-01 00:05:09  8438.2    NaN
1 2016-07-01 00:05:19  8422.4      g
```

You can also specify width of columns:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 fwidths = [20,12,2],
                 names=['date','time','float','string'], 
                 parse_dates=[['date','time']])
print (df)
            date_time   float string
0 2016-07-01 00:05:09  8438.2    NaN
1 2016-07-01 00:05:19  8422.4      g
```